# m2e pro https:// issue for ebay listings

Tags: image-upload, https, ebay, m2epro

as you all know if you are running your full site on https:// and serving images from https:// as well, it will cause an issue when listing on ebay. as ebay will not show the image when seraching for product or thumbnail.

for us the issue was, our images were hosted on differente server (STIC) for which we can not control of change any thing. as it will effect our rest of site. but the images are available on both https:// and http://, but we receive them as https:// becuase of ssl on our server

the issue is with ebay. They dont seem to like any image sent from https://

there is one solution for you. edit all products one by one and remove "s" from https://, but it is very time consuming.

we have contacted ebay and m2e pro, but both were unable to help.

Comment: This close has to be one of the more retarded ones. While the answer specified as close reason aims at general product recommendations and product support questions we here have a programming specific question to one of the biggest Magento Extensions which can be solved by extending it (programmatically). Think twice, where else should such a question be asked? http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/a/74/5 even says `we should encourage them to become part of the ecosystem of this site` But thinking seems to become less popular when it comes to rep hungry voters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution we found.

go in file

> app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Magento/Product.php

find the line

```
return str_replace(' ', '%20', $url);
```

and replace it with

```
return str_replace(array('https://', ' '), array('http://', '%20'), $url);
```

save refresh the cache and you are all done.

(just make sure your images are accessable on both https:// and http://)

hope this will help some one. 
vote if you like the answer.